# Add class in program C#

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
        Console.Write("Red = ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!Double.TryParse(input, out red))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have not entered an appropriate value!");
        }

        Console.Write("Green = ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!Double.TryParse(input, out green))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have not entered an appropriate value!");
        }

        Console.Write("Green = ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!Double.TryParse(input, out green))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have not entered an appropriate value!");
        }
```

and I'd like to replace the same parts.
I created class

```
public class ConverNumber
{
    public string InputString { get; private set; }
    public double Number { get; private set; }

    public static void ConvertNumber(string inputString, out double number)
    {
        if (!Double.TryParse(inputString, out number))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have not entered an appropriate value!");
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't understand how to use it?
And I'm not sure maybe i should create a method?

Comment: I have doubts that **you** created class which you don't know how to use

Comment: I have only recently been studying C# and it's difficult for me.

Comment: @Heidel start from methods then. Classes will be later

Comment: I'm reading books and watching videos, but I think I should to make different exercises to get practice. I added my own answer below.

Comment: lazyberezovsky - Not very constructive. @Heidel I think it's great you are trying to learn, but perhaps SO is not the best place to post questions in this format. I suggest you Google for C# tutorials, and you will find many that cover the basics of classes and methods. We can provide you with links if you like.

Comment: @Nick I will be glad if u provide me links.

Comment: @Heidel Here's a few to get you started: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp.html http://www.csharp-station.com/tutorials/lesson01.aspx http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e9fdcd/basics-of-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use it like this:

```
Console.Write("Red = ");
input = Console.ReadLine();
ConverNumber.ConvertNumber(input, out red);
```

and so on

Answer (score 5):

If you simply want to invoke the method, you should replace the following code:

```
Console.Write("Green = ");
input = Console.ReadLine();

if (!Double.TryParse(input, out green))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have not entered an appropriate value!");
}
```

with this

```
Console.Write("Green = ");
input = Console.ReadLine();

ConverNumber.ConvertNumber(input, out green);
```

Answer (score 0):

I a little changed my class

```
public class ConverNumber
{
    public string InputString { get; private set; }
    public double Number { get; private set; }

    public void ConvertNumber(string inputString, out double number)
    {
        if (!Double.TryParse(inputString, out number))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Вы не ввели значение!");
        }
    }
}
```

and used this code

```
        Console.Write("Red = ");

        var input = new ConverNumber();
        input.ConvertNumber(Console.ReadLine(), out red);

        Console.Write("Green = ");
        input.ConvertNumber(Console.ReadLine(), out green);

        Console.Write("Blue = ");
        input.ConvertNumber(Console.ReadLine(), out blue);
```

Comment: you should edit/update your original question, erase this answer, and accept the one below that says the same thing.